Supporting multiple fixture scopes per session?
We would like to be able to allow our users to define the lifetime of very specific objects, wrapped around an annotation provided by an inhouse framework. Is there a way to "update" a fixture's scope based on a user configuration?
For example, this is what I'm trying to do:
def _determine_scope(fixture_name, config) -> Literal[str]:
   # return 'function' or 'class' depending on the annotation config

@FixtureLifetimes("class")
class ClassOne:
    @pytest.fixture(scope=_determine_scope)
    def fixture1():
        pass

@FixtureLifetimes("function")
class ClassTwo:
    @pytest.fixture(scope=_determine_scope)
    def fixture2():
        pass

In this example, ClassOne has all fixtures scoped as class, and ClassTwo has all fixtures scoped with function.  I tried many things, like implementing various hook functions, but the _determine_scope method seems to run only once per session before any of the per-item hooks, and before any annotations are applied.
Has anyone tried to implement something similar? Looking for suggestions (or alternatives) in supporting behavior like this
